# MultipartContent response in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to have a possibility to return complex response for requests in Web API. For example I want to return stream with some complex object.
I tried to do it with MultipartFormDataContent:

```
    public static HttpResponseMessage GetMultipartResponse<T>(T responseData, Stream streamToReturn)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new MultipartContent
            {
                new StreamContent(streamToReturn),
                new ObjectContent<T>(responseData, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            }
        };
    }
```

I've got a normal `HttpResponseMessage` on server side. I can see by debugger how my Web API method returns this response, but on the client side I've got an error:

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNccnVzdGFtX3NhbGFraHV0ZGlub3ZcZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xGaWxlU2VydmljZUFQSVxGaWxlU2VydmljZUFQSVxhcGlcZ2V0?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2016 08:30:22 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1444
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}
```

There is no other exceptions on client or server side and i can't get some more information with turn on error detail:

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

**UPDATE:**
Try to read response on client side with:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
```

And got this exception:

> Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header starting with 'multipart/'.

Where do I go wrong?

**UPDATE 2:**
I have normal response on the server side:

```
    StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.MultipartContent, Headers:
    {
      Content-Type: multipart/multipart; boundary="3e6d3573-9031-41a7-b7f4-d1421bc1451d"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I return my multipart content inside using:

```
        using (var stream = MyFileStream())
        {
            var respone = MultipartResponseHelper.GetMultipartResponse(response, stream, Request);
            return respone;
        }
```

So it returns right response, but then stream inside multipartContent will disposed which is the reason of problem.